# Alexa.NET.Request.RequestVerification does not return back from execution

Tags: c#, alexa-skills-kit

I am performing the request validation which is required for Alexa skill's functional test before making your skill live. I have implemented the code in c# to provide the validation using Alexa.NET library.
All works fine except the last validation which requires the user to validate the entire raw body against the signature from request.
Although there is already an implementation for verifying the data in Alexa.NET.Request.RequestVerification class, when my execution enters this part, it doesn't come out of it.

If I don't use await and async, Alexa.NET.Request.RequestVerification.Verify returns Status = WaitingForActivation and Result as always FALSE.

I have searched around and only found the solutions to make my method async and use await. But none of it highlights the problem I am facing.
After making my method async, the debug cursor just won't return back from execution.

```
private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> IsRequestValidAsync(string signature, Uri signatureCertChainUrl, string body)
        {
            bool resultSet = await Alexa.NET.Request.RequestVerification.Verify(signature, signatureCertChainUrl, body);
            return resultSet;
        }
```

Alexa.NET.Request.RequestVerification.Verify should return back with some value.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :-

```
Task.FromResult(Alexa.NET.Request.RequestVerification.Verify(signature, 
signatureCertChainUrl, body));
```

I can't post a comment due to site restrictions hence posted an answer. Hope it helps!